# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 and Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to move my project to `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2`.

This is my old Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Profile("production")
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {
        return TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

}
```

Right now I faced a following issue:

```
1. The method builder() is undefined for the type TransportClient
2. InetSocketTransportAddress cannot be resolved to a type
```

On the Maven classpath I have `Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.0.M4`:

[image]

How to properly configure current version of Spring Data Elasticsearch ?

**UPDATED**

For my tests I use Embedded Elasticsearch with a following application.properties:

```
#Elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled=true
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.port=9250
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.home=target/test-elasticsearch-db
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.transport.tcp.connect_timeout=60s
```

This is my ES test config:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.elasticsearch")
public class ElasticsearchTestConfig {
}
```

Right now the test fails with a following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:726) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:458) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1478) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1089) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
```

What is wrong here and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had similar issue when migrating from spring-boot 1.5.6 to 2.0.0. The reason seems to be previous support for embedded elasticsearch is not more [supported](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server) and the same is reflected in spring-boot.

Previously leaving the following property empty

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes
```

put the following into use

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.home
```

and spring-boot created given directory in the target folder for embedded mode to run. With spring-boot 2.0.0 (spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar to be precise) cluster-nodes has become asserted for non-null value causing elasticsearchTemplate bean not to be created under the hood.

That is the reason why your app stop working so suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 2.0 uses Elasticsearch 5 which includes some breaking API changes. You would be shielded from those changes if you used Spring Boot's auto-configuration rather than trying to write your own.

All that's needed is a value for the `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` property. With that in place, Spring Boot will auto-configure both a `TransportClient` and an `ElasticsearchTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm absolutely okay with using of  default one if you will show how to adapt the current version to it. This is the purpose of my question.

Comment: What remains unclear? Just see the cluster nodes property with your existing `host:port` and you should be up and running

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I need some coffee to wake up. I missed this thing. I'll try it immediately after refreshing my Maven repository. Thanks!

Comment: to note: this property is now deprecated due to `TransportClient` deprecated also in `Spring 2.x`.