# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 and Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.0.M4 configuration

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to move my project to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 and Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.0.M4.

On the Maven classpath I have the following artifacts:

[image]

This are my old Spring Data Neo4j configurations:

**1.Bolt Driver**

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver;
import org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Profile("production")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.server.database.uri}")
    private String serverDatabaseUri;

    @Value("${neo4j.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${neo4j.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        Components.setDriver(new BoltDriver());

        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.example.domain.model.neo4j");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();

        // @formatter:off
        configuration
            .autoIndexConfiguration()
                .setAutoIndex("assert");
        configuration
            .driverConfiguration()
                .setCredentials(username, password)
                .setURI(serverDatabaseUri);
        // @formatter:on

        return configuration;
    }

}
```

**2. Embedded Driver** (for my tests)

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.domain.repository.neo4j")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jTestConfig {

    @Value("${neo4j.embedded.database.path}")
    private String storeDir;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        // Register your configuration here, this will confuse OGM so the driver you set below won't be destroyed
        Components.configure(configuration);

        // Register your driver
        EmbeddedDriver driver = new EmbeddedDriver(graphDatabaseService());
        Components.setDriver(driver);

        // Set driver class name so you won't get NPE
        configuration.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver");

        // Configure auto index
        configuration.autoIndexConfiguration().setAutoIndex("assert");

        return new SessionFactory(configuration, "com.example.domain.model.neo4j");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {

        // @formatter:off
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(storeDir))
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("neo4j.properties").getPath())
                .newGraphDatabase();
        // @formatter:on

        return graphDatabaseService;
    }

}
```

Right now I faced the following issue:

```
1. Components cannot be resolved
2. The constructor Configuration()
3. The method autoIndexConfiguration() is undefined for the type Configuration
4. The method driverConfiguration() is undefined for the type Configuration
```

How to properly implement these configurations for `Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.0.M4` ?

Comment: This is very similar to your [Elasticsearch question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263021/spring-boot-2-0-0-m2-and-spring-data-elasticsearch-configuration/45263178#45263178). Why not use Boot's auto-configuration for Neo4j?

Comment: Because I have to provide auto index "assert" value and configure a SessionFactory. I'm absolutely okay with using of  default one if you will show how to adapt the current version to it.